# Decoupled ODEs in Julia

Tags: julia, ode, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

The Lorenz attractor is the archetypal example in Julia documentation for solving systems of ODEs using `DifferentialEquations.jl`. Suppose I would like to solve that system for one thousand different initial conditions, keeping the attractor parameters fixed. What would be a good (i.e. efficient) way to solve and store the data for these 1000 decoupled ODEs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very interesting option is to work with ensembles:

https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/features/ensemble/

This feature offers support for various data analysis as well as good performance by using multi thread functionality. Should be a good starting point for anyone interested in running what in the original question should be called an `Ensemble`.